# Android In-app updates, where should i set update type?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

From where I can set app update type(IMMEDIATE/FLEXIBLE)? I can not find it in playstore console.

From where this code knowing available update type?

```
 // Creates an instance of the manager.
AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context);

// Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

// Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
    if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
          // For a flexible update, use AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE
          && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
              // Request the update.
    }
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56377914/what-purpose-does-appupdateinfo-isupdatetypeallowedappupdatetype-immediate-ser

Answer (score 1):

We need to call this: PUT API

```
https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/edits/{editId}/tracks/{track}
```

Pass data in body:

```
{
  "releases": [{
      "versionCodes": ["12"],
      "inAppUpdatePriority": 5,
      "status": "completed"
  }]
}
```

To determine priority, Google Play uses an integer value between 0 and 5, with 0 being the default, and 5 being the highest priority.
For example, consider the following strategy for setting update priority:

- Minor UI improvements: **Low-priority** update; request neither a **flexible** nor immediate update.
- Performance improvements: **Medium-priority** update; request a **flexible** update.
- Critical security update: **High-priority** update; require an **immediate** update.

**For Full info you can refer to below links:**

[https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#:~:text=In%2Dapp%20updates%20is%20a,0%20or%20higher](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#:%7E:text=In%2Dapp%20updates%20is%20a,0%20or%20higher).

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.tracks/update